# require_once in php

Tags: php, path, relative-path, require-once

I have a php file which has a require_once Statement (?)  this file is then in included in 2 other php files, one php file is in a sub directory so the layout is like this ("file1" and "file2" include the file "included"  which require_onces the "required")#

```
 L--subfolder1
 | L--file1
 L--subfolder2
 | L--required
 L--file2
 L--included
```

How can I reference the "required" file from the "included" file so that it will work from both file1 and file2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

always use absolute path

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/included";
```

or

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/subfolder2/required";
```

would work from anywhere

Comment: Thank you for the quick and correct answer I thought it would be a Server variable but wasn't sure which one even after looking in the php docs.

Comment: NOTE: that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not work in CRON only in a web browser

Answer (score 4):

You have to use absolute path to be able to require the file with the same code from anywhere.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/subfolder2/required');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dirname() in combination with the `__FILE__` constant. (If I understand you correctly you're including the file 'included' from both scripts and 'included' then includes some files?)
included(.php):

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__)."/subfolder2/required" );
```

Comment: Quick heads-up, dirname() returns the directory without a trailing slash, so you'll want to have that be `require_once( dirname(__FILE__)."/subfolder2/required" );` - note extra slash.